# filtering html tag in linux with sed

Tags: unix, sed, tags, sh, substitution

I'm having a problem trying to filter the following string in unix

```
<option value="20121209/YvegRascYTGxmWLUIrqW/por121209130030.jpg">2012-12-09 13:00h</option>
```

into:
`20121209/YvegRascYTGxmWLUIrqW/por121209130030.jpg` and `2012-12-09 13:00`.
I can find the beginning of the substrings I want, but not the ending.

```
 file=tmpfile
 read -r firstline<$file
 firstArg=$(echo $firstline | sed 's/^.*value="//' | sed 's/">*$//')
 echo $firstArg
 secondArg=$(echo $firstline | sed 's/^.*">//' | sed 's/h<*$//')
 echo $secondArg
```

The output is the following:

```
20121209/YvegRascYTGxmWLUIrqW/por121209130030.jpg">2012-12-09 13:00h</option>
2012-12-09 13:00h</option>
```

But what i really want is

```
20121209/YvegRascYTGxmWLUIrqW/por121209130030.jpg
2012-12-09 13:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor fix, you are missing `.` in two places (before the `*` of the 2nd `sed` on each line) :

```
 file=tmpfile
 read -r firstline<$file
 firstArg=$(echo $firstline | sed 's/^.*value="//' | sed 's/">.*$//')
 echo $firstArg
 secondArg=$(echo $firstline | sed 's/^.*">//' | sed 's/h<.*$//')
 echo $secondArg
```

**Input:**

```
<option value="20121209/YvegRascYTGxmWLUIrqW/por121209130030.jpg">2012-12-09 13:00h</option>
```

**Output:**

```
20121209/YvegRascYTGxmWLUIrqW/por121209130030.jpg
2012-12-09 13:00
```

**Explanation:**

- `*` matches the preceding character 0 or more times, so you were matching zero or more `>`'s and `<`'s previously.
- The `.` matches any character
- So `>.*` matches zero or more characters after `>`.

**Improvement:**

Additionally, the two `sed` lines can be better written as:

```
 firstArg=$(sed 's/^.*value="//;s/">.*$//' <<< "$firstline")
 secondArg=$(sed 's/^.*">//;s/h<.*$//' <<< "$firstline")
```

- Separate multiple replace patterns by `;` within one sed call
- `<<<` notation is called a [herestring](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html), you can save echos and pipes here by using it instead
- Always wrap variables with double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
sed -r 's@.*([0-9]{8}/[^"]+).*>([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[[:alnum:]]*)<.*@\1\n\2@g'
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
$ cat file.txt
<option value="20121209/YvegRascYTGxmWLUIrqW/por121209130030.jpg">2012-12-09 13:00h</option>
$ sed -r 's@.*([0-9]{8}/[^"]+).*>([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[[:alnum:]]*)<.*@\1\n\2@g' file.txt
20121209/YvegRascYTGxmWLUIrqW/por121209130030.jpg
2012-12-09 13:00h
```

Comment: This also works, but for my needs I prefer the solution below. Thank you